# php: split string into 3 parts by two delimiters where the first and the last "delimiters" are letters or numbers respectively

Tags: php, arrays, string, preg-match, preg-split

Any ideas how to split string into 3 parts where by two "delimiters" where the first and the last "delimiters" are letters or numbers respectively?

```
$str = "%@-H-e-l-l-o-7-9#$%";
```

would be split like this:

```
$arr=("%@-","H-e-l-l-o-7-9", "#$%");
```

and

```
$str = "Hi$73";
```

would be split like this:

```
$arr=("","Hi$73", "");
```

and

```
$str = "Беларусь!";
```

would be split like this:

```
$arr=("","Беларусь", "!");
```

and

```
$str = "!";
```

would be split like this:

```
$arr=("!","", "");
```

and

```
$str = "";
```

would be split like this:

```
$arr=("","", "");
```

and

```
$str = "ў55ЎW";
```

would be split like this:

```
$arr=("","ў55ЎW", "");
```

**which means it returns an array that consists of 3 elements (always), and the first and last symbols of the second element are numbers or latin/cyrillic letters, and the first and last(third) elements of this array contain absolutely no numbers and letters, and the join of that strings is the source string**

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do the job:

```
$in = array(
"%@-H-e-l-l-o-7-9#$%",
"Hi$73",
"Беларусь!",
"!",
"",
"ў55ЎW",
'$abc$$$',
"асоба_",
"34.5",
'#_!',
);

foreach($in as $elem) {
    preg_match('/^([^\pL\pN]*)((?=[\pL\pN]|$)[^_]*(?<=[\pL\pN])|^)?([^\pL\pN]*)$/u', $elem, $m);
    printf("'%15s'%s'%10s'\t%s'%10s'\t%s'%10s'%s", "$elem","=> (1): ",$m[1],"(2): ",$m[2], "(3): ",$m[3],"\n");

}
```

Where:

- `\pL` stands for any letter in any language
- `\pN` stands for any number in any language

**Output:**

```
'%@-H-e-l-l-o-7-9#$%'=> (1): '       %@-'   (2): 'H-e-l-l-o-7-9'    (3): '       #$%'
'          Hi$73'=> (1): '          '   (2): '     Hi$73'   (3): '          '
'Беларусь!'=> (1): '          ' (2): 'Беларусь' (3): '         !'
'              !'=> (1): '         !'   (2): '          '   (3): '          '
'               '=> (1): '          '   (2): '          '   (3): '          '
'        ў55ЎW'=> (1): '          ' (2): '   ў55ЎW' (3): '          '
'        $abc$$$'=> (1): '         $'   (2): '       abc'   (3): '       $$$'
'    асоба_'=> (1): '          '    (2): 'асоба'    (3): '         _'
'           34.5'=> (1): '          '   (2): '      34.5'   (3): '          '
'            #_!'=> (1): '       #_!'   (2): '          '   (3): '          '
```

Comment: you have `Array([0] => Hi$73
    [1] => 
    [2] => Hi
    [3] => $73)` . But the OP wanted `$arr=("","Hi$73", "");`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: True, I've edited the code, insert `$` in the character class.

Comment: Sorry for accepting as the best asnwer not yours.  Both answers are perfect but thanks to @RomanPerekhrest he found a minor mistake in your answer. That's the only reason I know how to mark an accepted answer. Otherwise, both are perfect. And thanks a lot to both of you.

Comment: @Haradzieniec: Don't worry, it's OK for me. Roman Perekhrest have answered before me.

Comment: @Toto, and seems like your code doesn't work for $abc$$$: <?php

$in = array(
"$abc$$$"
);

foreach($in as $elem) {
    preg_match('/^(\PL*)([\pL\d$-]*)(\PL*)$/u', $elem, $m);
    print_r($m);
}

?>  returns E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined variable: abc  (I didn't change your code to show an error although array consists of one element).

Comment: @Haradzieniec: See my edit, is it ok now? I'm using word boundary to discriminate non word part/word (and more) part

Comment: @Toto, thank you very much. Looks like underscore _ is a problem with a new code (tried many tests since this your comment). _ is treated as a letter :(   preg_match('/^(\PL*)(\b.*\b)?(\PL*)$/u', "асоба_", $arr);  $arr[3] is "" instead of _ and unfortunately $arr[2]="асоба_" respectively.

Comment: And one more:    preg_match('/^(\PL*)(\b.*\b)?(\PL*)$/u', '34.5', $m);
    print_r($m);    produces Array ( [0] => 34.5 [1] => 34.5 [2] => [3] => )   but 34.5 should be in [2]nd, not in first.  However, thank you for your help. I did a lot today thanks to you.

Comment: @Haradzieniec:See my new edit, it works now for any test cases, `34.5`, `асоба_` and `#_!`, these 2 last doesn't work with RomanPerekhrest's regex.

Comment: I confirm "#_!"  and "асоба_" doesn't work properly for the code suggested by @RomanPerekhrest.  Thanks a lot. That way I should accept your answer as a better one? Roman, sorry for that.

Answer (score 3):

The solution using `preg_match` and `array_slice` functions:

```
$str = "%@-H-e-l-l-o-7-9#$%";

preg_match('/^([^\w]*)(\w+.*\w+|\w)?([^\w]*)$/iu', $str, $matches);
$parts = array_slice($matches, 1);

print_r($parts);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => %@-
    [1] => H-e-l-l-o-7-9
    [2] => #$%
)
```

This approach will work for all of your presented input cases

Comment: seems like you code doesn't work for 1 letter case. Empty array for <?php
$str = "к";

preg_match('/^([^\w]*)(\w+.*\w+)?([^\w]*)$/iu', $str, $matches);
$parts = array_slice($matches, 1);

print_r($parts);
?>

Comment: @Haradzieniec, check my update. It should work fine now

Comment: Looks like it works! The only issue I've found _ underscore is treated as letter, but that' because of \w which is any word character (letter, number, underscore). No questions regarding underscore. That might be a separate SO question. Thanks a lot for your help! I really appreciate it. Thank YOU!