# php: string is double-quoted, not single-quoted. How to fix?

Tags: php, string, http-post, double-quotes

I was asking [this SO question php: split string into 3 parts...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41910966/php-split-string-into-3-parts-by-two-delimiters-where-the-first-and-the-last-d) and got excellent answers. However, I faced an issue. The issue is double-quoted string to process. Because of that it doesn't work as expected in one case when `$`sign is within the string.

```
$str = $_POST['source'];//comes double-quoted, example: "$abc$";
```

That way the code from the answer from the question mentioned above is:

```
<?php
$str = "$abc$$$";//comes from _POST['source'];

preg_match('/^([^\w]*)(\w+.*\w+)?([^\w]*)$/iu', $str, $matches);
$parts = array_slice($matches, 1);

print_r($parts);
?>
```

doesn't work and causes `E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined variable:` 
From what I've found the problem is `"$abc$$$"` is double quoted, not single quoted. That causes $ treating as a variable: [SO: Dollar ($) sign in password string treated as variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557834/dollar-sign-in-password-string-treated-as-variable)

I've tried

```
$str = $_POST['source'];
$str = (string)$str;// I hoped to convert "$abc$$$" to '$abc$$$' (to make single-quoted)
```

but that doesn't help.
Any ideas how to face with this issue?

Comment: Any reasons to downvote? Downvoter, could you please explain why? Thanks.

Comment: `$str = _POST['source'];` I'm not grasping here. Why are you intentionally removing the `$` from a superglobal?

Comment: That's a typo. Updated. Thanks.

Comment: No it works just fine.

Comment: @Fred-ii- - updated typo in both places, thank you very much.

Comment: `$str = $_POST['source'];` will give you the value: `$abc$$$` and isn't double quoted (it's only when you write a string yourself in your code that the quoting matters).. I think your error is somewhere else. On what line do you get that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works just fine. ***Its your testing that is causing the issue.***

Do this instead

```
$_POST['source'] = '$abc$$$';

$str = $_POST['source'];

preg_match('/^([^\w]*)(\w+.*\w+)?([^\w]*)$/iu', $str, $matches);
$parts = array_slice($matches, 1);

print_r($parts);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => $
    [1] => abc
    [2] => $$$
)
```

Additional Example

Look at this simple test. I load a variable using a single quoted string and var_dump shows it to me as a double quoted string.

```
$test = '$var';
var_dump($test);
```

Result

```
string(4) "$var"
```

Its just how the dump functions decide to show a string, the string has not been changed

Its only if within PHP itself you use a `$` when creating a string variable using a double quoted string literal that this variable expansion takes place. This is something PHP does and nothing intrinsic about double quoted literals.

So this

```
$test = "$var";
```

Will generate an error if `$var` does not exists, or expand it if it does. But only because it being done in PHP code.

Comment: which would be a duplicate of what they posted in the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557834/dollar-sign-in-password-string-treated-as-variable as per http://stackoverflow.com/a/2557845/1415724

Comment: Theoretically of course. If what you posted here doesn't solve it, then something else is failing them. What they didn't post were the expected results.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, you'd be right, but it comes double-quoted from front end. There it comes from textarea with jQuery .text() method. I didn't find how to pass to back end single quoted string (with javascript) and I didnt' find how to "convert" double quoted received string on the back end side with php.

Comment: No it does not. It is a string literal. It may be shown to you in a var_dump or Print_r in double quotes. But it does not come that way its only shown that way in a dump

Comment: Remember a string is just a set of bytes in a memory location with a start address and a `\0` at the end. There is no such thing as single or double quotes in the data

Comment: @RiggsFolly, you refer to a SO question Dollar ($) sign in password that I've mentioned even in my question. Didn't help. Let me attach a screen of my code/debug.

Comment: @Haradzieniec Do you understand what I am saying. Your only issue is the way you are testing the code you have been given in the previous question

Comment: See my additional proof of situation

Comment: See additional explanation, I am struggling to make this plain I am afraid

Comment: @RiggsFolly, looks like you're right.  The solution may be the problem, not quotes. Yes, you're right. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Phew! Thanks for the feedback